# "php artisan migrate" shows "nothing to migrate"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, artisan-migrate, laravel-artisan

I am new to laravel.
I am working on laravel version 6.
I have created migration.
It works nicely the first time, but if i change something in the migration file and then i run `php artisan migrate` it shows `nothing to migrate`.
I tried `php artisan migrate --path` as well but it does not work.
To make it work i have to delete the migration file and create it again.
I don't want to use `php artisan migrate:fresh`.

what should i do to run only one migrations file which has been changed?

Comment: try `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Comment: `migrate:refresh` will delete all table and then run migration again.

Comment: Please use `php artisan migrate:rollback` for last created migration file.

Comment: so ```php artisan migrate:rollback``` will not drop all the tables?

Comment: All of this information about `rollback` and `reset` aside, if you want to change a migration that has already been run, the rule of thumb is "don't". Create a new migration that changes the table (add/drop/change column, etc) and run `php artisan migrate` again. Migrations are meant to be a "moving forward" type of thing so you don't have to run rollbacks and risk dataloss.

Comment: If you don't like to create a new migration file, [make your own artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/commands).

Answer (score 4):

When you run `php artisan migrate` it'll check migration table if there is no new file in the migration folder it'll show you nothing to migrate.

> If you want to rollback last migration.

To `rollback` the latest migration operation, you may use the rollback command. This command rolls back the last "batch" of migrations, which may include multiple migration files:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

It'll delete the last created table.

The `migrate:reset` command will roll back all of your application's migrations:

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```

The `migrate:fresh` command will drop all tables.

```
php artisan migrate:fresh

php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

more info : [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/migrations#rolling-back-migrations)

Comment: Is it `migrate:fresh` or `migrate:refresh`? Edit: Nevermind; I see it in the newer documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations

Comment: `migrate:refresh` will delete all table and  auto-create it again. `migrate:fresh` only delete table.

Comment: If you want to delete only last created table you must use `migrate:rollback`

Comment: I don't mind but in new document migration concept is the same.https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#rolling-back-migrations

Comment: Gotcha; I hadn't seen the `fresh` command before, but seems to be a newer addition (Laravel 5.5+) that effectively does the same thing as `refresh`, but doesn't rollback; it just drops everything and does it again. Good to know!

Answer (score 2):

Sadly impossible. The best workaround is to use seeders and use `php artisan db:seed` after you use `php artisan migrate:fresh`. Why don't you want to use that?

Comment: Because it will drop my users table as well. so everytime i make some changes to the migration file, i'll have to add user as well.

Comment: @AkshayRathod for adding data seeders are invented

Comment: i am new to laravel. i don't know what seeders are, i have to look that up.

Answer (score 2):

there is two things to do you that you can use
1. In your database there is a table called migrations. Delete the rows from there which one is you want to migrate. That should be there.
2.create a folder inside of database/migrations/folder. And put the migrations file inside the folder then in your command prompt run this below command:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=database/migrations/folder
```

option 2 is better than the option 1. I always use this. So i recommend option 2. This should be work

Answer (score 2):

For every modification on existing (already migrated tables) you will have to make a new migration with modifications only. If you have "users" table migration `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table` like:

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');         
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and you need to split "name" column, will have to `php artisan make:migration alter_table_users --table="users"` and add what you want to change:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->renameColumn('name', 'first_name'); // rename column
    $table->string('last_name'); // add new column  });
```

Reverse

```
public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('first_name', 'name');
            $table->dropColumn('last_name');
        });
    }
```

Nou you can use `php artisan migrate`

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#modifying-columns

Answer (score 2):

If you  have  seeder  data   then  you  simply  do: php artisan  migrate: fresh  -- seed . It  help to  re-migrate  your  migration  with  seeder  data

Answer (score 1):

You didn't understand well migrations mechanics.

> but if i change something in the migration file and then i run php artisan migrate it shows nothing to migrate

You write migration to make some changes in database and run it once. If you want to do next updates to database you need next migration.

During development process you can rerun migrations by `php artisan migrate:fresh`, but on production make sure your migration makes everything you want.

Laravel stores informations about migrations in database in table 'migrations'. If you want to reset some migrations files you can try deleting or edit some records in that table.

Comment: The `migrations` table stores the name (key) of the migration and the batch. There's not much point to manually editing that table when you have the various migration commands to do it for you. It also doesn't have an `id` or `autoincrement` column, so running SQL against it is sometimes a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the migration has already run or not in the migration table.
If its run then there will be a row respective to your migration.
If you do changes to an old migration than nothing will be reflected when you run command php artisan migrate, as it has already been migrated.

Answer (score 1):

No one replied question "Akshay Rathod" but "Militaru" replied exactly what he need `php artisan make:migration alter_table_users --table="users"` and copy you new fields inside the up() function as under

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('userimage')->nullable();
            $table->string('contact_no')->nullable();
            $table->string('website')->nullable();
            $table->string('country_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('timezone')->nullable();
            $table->string('currency')->nullable();
            $table->string('communication_email')->default(1);
            $table->string('communication_phone')->default(0);
            $table->string('allow_marketing')->default(0);
        });
    }
```